# Ternary Plot detail/clipping in R

Tags: r

I have used [triax.plot](http://search.r-project.org/library/plotrix/html/triax.plot.html) to create a ternary plot.

```
require(plotrix)
data <- read.csv("~/R/datasets/data.csv")
triax.plot(data[1:18721,],main="ternary plot", tick.labels=list(b=seq(10,90,by=10),l=seq(10,90,by=10),r=seq(10,90,by=10)), pch=4)
```

However most of the data forms a cluster that I want to display in more detail. I would like to edit the axis range (not the labels, not the ticks) to display only the relevant area of the original plot
[highlighted in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYR4i.png). The resulting clipping would also be a  isosceles triangle.

Apparently triax.plot has no option for this. Or am I missing something? Any suggestions for alternative approaches are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried ggtern? https://github.com/nicholasehamilton/ggtern

Comment: Not yet, but it looks promising! :-)

Comment: Thanks, @timelyportfolio! I have been able to solve my problem with ggtern.

Answer (score 1):

There is a straightforward solution using the [`Ternary` package](https://ms609.github.io/Ternary/articles/Ternary.html):

```r
TernaryPlot(xlim = c(0.28, 0.38), ylim = c(0.1, 0.2), padding = 0.04)
TernaryPoints(data)
```

Set `xlim` and `ylim` to the range that you wish to crop the panel to.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @martin-smith for taking the time to answer my question! I have since started using Python, and currently cannot confirm your answer solves my question. Hopefully someone else will find it helpful!